# How to put youtube video on the same site

Tags: html, css, video, youtube

If you go to the official website of Overwatch (https://playoverwatch.com/en-us/) and click on the "WATCH TRAILER" button, the youtube video will appear on the same website without having to direct you to the original youtube page where that video came from. How did they do that?

Comment: Youtube provides an embed tag for every video which you insert in your page HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's called using embed videos. you can do it with using `iframes`

**YouTube Video Id**

YouTube will display an id (like vhjTYfG), when you open video. You can use this id, and refer to your video in the HTML code.

**To play your video on a web page, do the following:**

```
- Upload the video to YouTube
- Take a note of the video id
- Define an <iframe> element in your web page
- Let the src attribute point to the video URL
- Use the width and height attributes to specify the dimension of the player
- Add any other parameters to the URL (see below)
```

This is an example code,

```
 <iframe width="420" height="315"
src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/vhjTYfG">
</iframe>
```

*Read more here. [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_youtube.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Mr Vishwa is right. I just wanted to add.

Please have a look at this url
https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference

playoverwatch.com is using a similar technology